# How can I connect to AWS Documentdb with Robo 3T?

Tags: robo3t, aws-documentdb

Using the latest Robo 3T and the command line provided by AWS

```
mongodb://<dbname>:<insertYourPassword>@example-db.cluster-c2e1234stuff0e.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017
```

I get this Error:

> Reason:
>   SSL tunnel failure: Network is unreachable or SSL connection rejected by server. 
>   Reason: Connect failed

I have also tried following [THIS](https://medium.com/@maxy_ermayank/aws-documentdb-mongodb-compatibility-31c0013f1867) walkthrough but had no joy.

I have read that it is possible to SSH to a EC2 instance on the same VPC and access documentdb this way but ideally I would like to access it directly and not pay for an extra EC2 instance. If I have that right?

I have tried via Mongo shell too and get the following response:

```
Error: couldn't connect to server example-db.cluster-c2eblahblaho0e.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to example-db.cluster-c2eblahblaho0e.eu-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 (<IP address>) :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect is happening is that either you do not have an EC2 instance in the same VPC as your DocumentDB cluster or that EC2 instance is not reachable from your laptop. I'd first connect to the EC2 instance with SSH to establish connectivity and then use that EC2 instance to SSH proxy from Robo3T.

For context, Amazon DocumentDB clusters deployed within a VPC can be accessed directly by EC2 instances or other AWS services that are deployed in the same VPC. Additionally, Amazon DocumentDB can be accessed by EC2 instances or other AWS services in different VPCs in the same region or other regions via VPC peering.

The advantage of deploying clusters within a VPC is that VPCs provide a strong network boundary to the Internet. A common way to connect to DocumentDB from your laptop is to create an EC2 instance within the same VPC as your DocumentDB cluster and SSH tunnel through that EC2 instance to your cluster: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html

To minimize costs for local development, start with the smallest EC2 instance size and utilize the start/stop functionality when not using the cluster.

The same can be done with DocumentDB. When you are developing, you can save on instance costs by stopping the cluster when it is no longer needed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/db-cluster-stop-start.html

An alternative is to utilize AWS Cloud9: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-with-cloud9.html. This solution still requires an EC2 instance in the same VPC as your Amazon Document. What is useful about this solution is that Cloud9 provides a mechanisms to automatically shutdown the EC2 instance if it has been idle for 30-minutes, for example, to help save costs.